# Как исправить ошибку при использовании клавиатуры keyboa

Tags: python, sqlite, telegram-bot

**Скажи как исправить ошибку при использовании клавиатуры [keyboa](https://github.com/torrua/keyboa)?**
Когда я ставлю так `query = call.data` и запускаю бота, то он делает всю процедуру как надо (первый раз). Но когда я второй раз пытаюсь сделать еще раз процедуру (после нажатия или отправки сообщения) то он сразу выдает ошибку. То есть я нажимаю на кнопку меню (любую) и вылазит ошибка. **Как это можно поправить?**

Ошибка (второй раз)

```
"... main.py", line 106, in add_point
    query = call.data       
AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'data'
```

Функционал ()

```
from keyboa import keyboa_maker

numbers = list(range(1, 25))
key = keyboa_maker(items=numbers, items_in_row=6, copy_text_to_callback=True)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def main_menu(message):
    if message.text == KEYBOARD['PEREF_OBSL']:
        msg = "Добавь описание:"
        sent = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, msg)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(sent, add_desc)

def add_desc(message):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(settings.DATABASE)
    cursor = conn.cursor()   
    try:
        sql = f"""UPDATE user_statistics SET desc = ? WHERE user_id = {message.from_user.id} AND request_id = (SELECT MAX(request_id) FROM user_statistics);"""
        query = message.text
        cursor.execute(sql, (query,))
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        msg =  'Выберите число'
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        sent = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, msg, reply_markup=key )
        bot.register_next_step_handler(sent, add_point)
    except sqlite3.DatabaseError as error:
        msg = f'Ошибка: <b>{message.text}</b>.'
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, msg, reply_markup=keyboard, parse_mode='HTML')
    
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def add_point(call):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(settings.DATABASE)
    cursor = conn.cursor()   
    try:
        sql = f"""UPDATE user_statistics SET point = ? WHERE user_id = {call.from_user.id} AND request_id = (SELECT MAX(request_id) FROM user_statistics);"""
        query = call.data
        cursor.execute(sql, (query,))
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        msg =  'Дата'
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        sent = bot.send_message(call.from_user.id, msg, parse_mode='HTML')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(sent, add_date)
    except sqlite3.DatabaseError as error:
        msg = f'Ошибка: <b>{call.data}</b>.'
        bot.send_message(call.from_user.id, msg, reply_markup=keyboard, parse_mode='HTML')
    
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Возможно поможет замена строки

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda message: True)
```

на

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
```